# How to render a component with dynamic content in a page using an npm-based static site generator?

Tags: javascript, node.js, static-site

The goal is to render a component with dynamic content in a page using an npm-based static site generator:

I can't seem to find a solution to this in in Harp, Brunch or Metalsmith. I have been playing with each of these and it feels like I am going about this the wrong way.

The structure will be something like:

```
/pages
 |_ home.??
 |_ about.??
/partial
 |_ header.??
 |_ body.??
 |_ portfolio-item.??
/data
 /home
  partial-1.??
  partial-2.??
  partial-3.??
  partial-4.??
```

Now I need home to include each partial with the data passed to the partial.

```
//home.??
include header with partial-1
include body with partial-2
include portfolio-item with partial-3
include portfolio-item with partial-4
```

And each partial needs markup:

```
//portfolio-item.??
<p>
  {{project-description}}
</p>
```

And each data item needs to have the relating id for data:

```
//sort of like json
{
  project-description: whatever i need
}
```

Why do this? I want to:

- Separate markup from data
- Have files act like a CMS
- Speed up development as I am not copying partials around if I am reusing them. (For example, harp supports unique values for files but not reusing files with unique values)

Any tips will be great! I think jade or Ejs might be solutions, but the data might have to be manipulated by some custom code. This, however, feels like someone has done this before.

Comment: This is a seriously big topic. Have you considered using [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/)? It sounds almost exactly like what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi @MikeC , I think you might have hit the nail on the head on this one. I will have to look at their getting started and get back to this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After @MikeC pointed me in the direction of Jekyll I went ahead and explored it.

By using the [documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/home/) I came up with the following solution to the problem:

The standard Jekyll structure is was used.

We must make the builder partial that will add components from data files

```
{% assign page_data = site.data.[page.context] %}
{% assign counter = 0 %}

{% for partial_name in page_data.partials %}
    {% assign counter = counter | plus:1 %} 
    {% include {{ partial_name }}.html %}
{% endfor %}
```

In about.md add the following

```
---
layout: page
title: About
context: about
permalink: /about/
---
{% include builder.html %}
```

Then add a partial that you would like to test on like _includes/hello-text.html.

```
{% capture data_file %}{{ page.context }}-{{ counter }}{% endcapture %}

{% assign context = site.data.[data_file] %}
<p>
    {{ context.content }}
</p>
```

Finally add your data files _data/about.json

```
{
    "partials": ["foobar", "foobar", "foobar"],
}
```

and _data/about-1.json

```
{
    "content": "helloworld"
}
```

You can add about-2.json for the second partial and so on. I would still appreciate any improvements on this issue if anyone has any suggestions you can check out the [repo on github](https://github.com/bitlinguist/jekyll-testing) to bash it out.